# Limit Django users to one single group

Tags: django

I'm rather surprised that this hasn't been asked before, but I need to limit my Users in Django to only belong to one single Group. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

One option can be that in your view or form, before you add more groups to the user you make a validation:

```
if user.groups.exists():
    for g in user.groups.all():
        user.groups.remove(g)

user.groups.add(group_to_add)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the Groups field widget :

```
groups = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Group.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple
    )
```

and then remove the 'multiple' attribute using Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id_groups").removeAttr("multiple");
});
```